# What is a simple way to check if two words overlap at all in Python using indices

Tags: python

I am trying to determine whether or not two words overlap inside of a string by using their indices (start and end positions) and not the word.

For example:

```
str = "testme"
start_word_1 = 0
end_word_1 = 4
start_word_2 = 4
end_word_2 = 6
```

In this example str[0:4] is "test" and str[4:6] is "me".  These do not overlap but the end of word 1 is the same as start of word 2. So these are okay.  I just feel like I'm making it too complicated and there is more simple code for this to cover words that entirely overlap and words that only partially overlap. Thank you!

To clarify overlap:  I mean in the string slice str[0:4] ("test") and str[4:6] ("me")  do not overlap. They are okay.

But str[0:5] ("testm") does overlap with str[4:6] ("me").

Also, str[0:6] ("testme") does overlap with str[1:4] ("est"), where this one here "est" is completely inside of "testme."

This is going to be used for text highlighting where I do not want anything to be conflicting highlights.

Comment: What does it mean when a word 'overlaps'?

Comment: I would probably do this with ranges and set intersection

Comment: I mean the text spans overlap, meaning two concepts overlap. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example where the strings do overlap

Comment: I added few examples. If you know of a better word for "overlap" let me know. haha. I couldn't think of one. :)

Comment: It's late on Friday so bear with me if I am missing a few cases, but doesn't `start_word_2 < end_word_1` essentially cover everything, so long as word 1 is to the left of word 2? So to your first example `4<4` is False (no overlap), your second `4<5` overlaps, and your third `1<6` overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this is pretty simple and meets your (admittedly a little odd) requirements. Note this is using strings that look like slices, corresponding to your use of indices rather than the words themselves:

```
In [1]: def words_overlap(slice1, slice2):
   ...:     """Take two strings representing slices (e.g. 'x:y') and
   ...:     return a boolean indicating whether they overlap"""
   ...:     if slice1[0] < slice2[0]:  # slice1 is leftmost
   ...:         return slice2[0] < slice1[2]  # slice2 ends before slice1 starts
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return slice1[0] < slice2[2]
   ...: 

In [2]: words_overlap('1:3', '2:4')
Out[2]: True

In [3]: words_overlap('2:4', '1:3')
Out[3]: True

In [4]: words_overlap('2:3', '5:7')
Out[4]: False

In [5]: words_overlap('0:4', '4:6')
Out[5]: False
```

All it does is detect which slice is leftmost using a simple less than test, and then tell you if the rightmost slice starts before the leftmost one ends.

Should be quite efficient since it only involves two integer comparisons.

Comment: Yes this worked and helped me think it through and keep it simple, which it is, and I was making it ridiculously complicated. ;) Thanks!!

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but if anyone sees this answer, it wouldn't work for indices > 9 because you took a slice.  I guess you'd have to preprocess that.

Comment: @jennifer06262016 It was just an example. For two-digit indices (and further) you need to make it more robust by actually splitting the slices like so: `start_word_1, end_word_1 = slice1.split(':')` and then work with them that way.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist May I know how you could replace/del the overlapped session from slice 1 and slice 2 in place and then put the overlapped session into an array as keeping record?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like that?

```
start1 < end2 and start2 < end1
```

This means: each of the two words begins *earlier* than the other word ends, so they do overlap

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**: Word 2 is a substring of (or matches) Word 1 (or vice versa)

```
word1 in word2 or word2 in word1
```

ex. "StackExchange" and "tack"

**Case 2**: Word 2 overlaps at Word 1's end

`for i in range(1, len(word2)):
    word1.endswith(word2[:-i])`

ex. "stackoverflow" and "flowing"

**Case 3**: Word 2 overlaps at Word 1's beginning

`for i in range(1, len(word2)):
    word1.startswith(word2[i:])`

ex. "badges" and "terribad"

Comment: This 'works' (maybe violates OP's "without using the word" constraint) but I think it can be done a lot more efficiently than these loops.

Comment: @two-bit-alchemist I agree, this should not be used as algorithm, it simply shows how to recognize each set of overlaps using the substrings. Any non-transforming, non-compressing algorithm would consider `n+m-1` string pairings in the worst-case scenario. Case 1 make `n-m+1`, Case 2 make `m-1`, and Case 3 make `m-1` comparisons.

Comment: @Dave just ask, did you figure out how to get it done more efficiently than these loops

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for *unique* overlapping chars:

```
>>> set("some word").intersection(set("other word"))
{' ', 'd', 'e', 'o', 'r', 'w'}
```

or the number of unique overlapping unique chars:

```
>>> set("some word").intersection(set("other word"))
6
```

Comment: The question is about using indices, not the actual text.